# import eclipse preferences on the command line

Tags: eclipse

I'm creating an automated installation of a java development environment and I would like to import eclipse preferences using the command line. Is it possible?

I don't want to run eclipse with -configuration parameter. I want the same functionality as in file -> import.

Or maybe, if this is not possible, can somebody point me to in which files are installed jres configuration and cvs repositories configuration? Then I can maybe change the files and it will do what I need.

Thanks

Kelly

Comment: I also wounder if this is also possible to do it from old version of Eclipse to the new one.

Comment: That works mostly, but you don't know afterwards where it breaks. Most of the time, you can use the old workspace with a new eclipse distro, and eclipse will use it seamlessly.

Comment: @mliebelt, I prefer to define new clean workspace and just export and import my projects and than I manually compare the setting and change them. As a bonus, I learn about new settings. But it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score -3):

We have good experiences with the following process:

1. Create a new eclipse installation and a corresponding workspace to your liking: configuration, settings, reasonable defaults, ...
2. Try to find a structure like:

   ```
   /<base-dir>
     /eclipse - Your eclipse installation directory
     /ws - Your corresponding workspace directory
     eclipse.bat - Your start script for eclipse with that workspace
   ```
3. Test your configuration with a small set of projects, do the normal workflow and keep an eye to the configuration and settings.
4. If everything is ok, zip the whole directory `<base-dir>` and provide that on a network drive or ftp server for others.

That is easy to develop, and easy to adapt. Every now and then, you can update your base installation, and tell the developers to throw away their old installation and unzip a new one.

Comment: What is the value in downvoting a 7+ year old answer? I never understood that ... Everyone should know, that a 7 year old question and answer is ...old.

Answer (score -4):

You can try to File->Export, under General you can find Preferences. But it is very limited. To import do the same thing File->Import, under General you can find Preferences.